# handle onErrorReturn method efficiently with RxAndroid

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I am using observable pattern to process my responseBody from server.

**Goal:** This is the code I am using, in error case I want to display toast with error msg, just to test now I had put a log msg and it displays log message perfectly. But when I try to do anything else in that method i.e. displaying toast with error message or pushing message via bus to activity it crashes and error says

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread. Add `onError` handling.
```

`Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

What am I doing wrong ?

```
myRetrofit.startPatrol(path.getId(), 8)

            .map(result -> {

                if (result.isSuccessful()) {
                    try {
                        String responseBody = result.body().string();
                        JSONObject fullObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);
                        String patrolID = fullObject.getString("id");
                        pref.setPatrolID(patrolID);
                        emitStoreChange(new CobaltStoreChangeEvent(Constants.PATROL_STARTED));
                        Log.d(TAG, "startPatrol: " + patrolID);
                    } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    Utils.errorHandle(activity, result);
                }
                //I dont need to return anything here I just want success.
                return null;
            })
            .onErrorReturn(throwable -> {
                //Errors are on this toast line.
                Toasty.error(App.getAppContext(), throwable.getMessage()).show();
               //tried calling emitStoreChange method as above but same result in error. Putting only log works.
                Log.d(TAG, "startPatrol: "+throwable.getMessage());
                return throwable.getMessage();
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe();
```

Comment: Nulls are not allowed in Observables. Furthermore you need to plase observeOn before executing UI-Code. ObserveOn will switch thread from pipeline-position for down-stream.

Comment: so instead of null is `Observable.empty()` good ?

Comment: Yeah, sounds good. Please note that side-effects should not be done in operators other than do*-Methods. Please use pipeline steps to transform data and do your side-effects in the subscribe-part. Place a observeOn Android.Scheduler before the subscribe to execute UI-related actions on UI-Thread.

Comment: perfect.. can you briefly explain what do you mean by "pipeline steps to transform data"

Comment: So a pipeline-step is an operator like map/ flatMap or other operators. Data enters the the first operator and will go through each operator. At the same time there can only be one item which is in the pipeline. Therefore the subscribe onError/ onNext/ onComplete methods are synchronized. This means you can not have race-conditions. With subscribeOn you tell RxJava invoke the creation of the observable on given scheduler. With observeOn you tell the system to switch thread. Further reading: http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.de/2016/02/rxjava-understanding-observeon-and.html